# How to opend the "ntx" file generated by Lunar DPX enCORE?

Tags: medical, information-extraction

I got some "ntx" files downloaded from Lunar DPX enCORE containing bone density info. I don't know how to open and extract information from it.

I tried to open it with binary code and had no idea of their meaning.

Comment: Sorry, the "ntf" should be "ntx".

Comment: You need to contact whoever created those files for the specification of the file format. This is not a suitable question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am also trying other approaches. Any help, suggestion, or codes are appreciated.